# new line character in product description

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-service-cloud

I have standard field Product description in salesforce.Can I have new line characters in the description for each product?If so how?

Answer (score 2):

Product Description is a long text field, so line breaks are fine.

You didn't say how you're creating the product descriptions. Assuming it's Apex, this is how you get line breaks in a string:

```
String description = 'Line 1\r\nLine2';
```